# TypeError trying to uploading a image with ImageField in django

Tags: python, django, image, types, upload

i am receiving this error while i am trying to upload a image with ImageField:

```
TypeError at /admin/article/articulo/7/change/
not all arguments converted during string formatting
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/article/articulo/7/change/
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
not all arguments converted during string formatting
Exception Location:  
C:\Users\HOME\ProyectosDjango\weMarket\apps\article\models.py in 
upload_location, line 6
```

This is a part from the models.py with the ImageField:

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "static/img/" %(instance.id, filename)

class Articulo(models.Model):

...

nombre_imagen=models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
    null=True, blank=True, 
    width_field="width_field", 
    height_field="height_field")
width_field=models.IntegerField(default=0)
height_field=models.IntegerField(default=0)

...

def __str__(self):
    return "("+str(self.id)+") " + self.nombre_producto
```

This is a part from the forms if you need it:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Articulo

    fields = [
        'nombre_imagen',
        'nombre_producto',
        'id_clasificacion_fk',
        'Descripcion',
        'long_descripcion',
        'precio',
        'cantidad',
        ]
```

And the HTML with the form:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10">
    <form method="post">
        <h5 class="mb-3">Agregar artículo</h5>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Guardar 
cambios</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="{% static 'img/handpen.png'%}"width="350px" height="310px" 
/>
</div>
</div>
```

If anyone can help me let me know.

Thank you!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `upload_location` function has an error. You are trying to format a string but have not included "replacement" tokens

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "static/img/" % (instance.id, filename)
```

Should probably be

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "static/img/%s/%s/" % (instance.id, filename)
```

Comment: Yes you are right! But i have another problem, when i try to upload the file it says "the nombre_imagen attribute has no file associated with it" and it doesnt show me the image. And when i see the nombre_imagen in DB, there is no path in there. What could be wrong?

Comment: in the html form you have to add enc_type https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp  for uploading files in general.